# Ehcache and SLF4J error

Tags: configuration, slf4j, ehcache

I am new to Ehcache and Slf4j .I am using ehcache-2.6.6

I have used

**slf4j-api-1.6.1 jar**

**slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1 jar**

When i extracted ehcache-2.6.6-distribution.tar these two jars were in folder lib .

This is my ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">


    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <defaultCache
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
            maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            statistics="false">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="myCache1"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300"
           timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>
    
</ehcache>
```

This is my code

```
package cache;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;

public class EhcacheWrapper {
    private static CacheManager cacheManager;
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "myCache1";

   

   

   
    private static Ehcache getCache(String cacheName) {
        if (cacheManager == null) {
            cacheManager = CacheManager.create("ehcache.xml");
        }

        Ehcache cache = null;
        if (cacheManager != null) {
           
            cache = cacheManager.getEhcache(cacheName);
        }

        return cache;
    }
 
    public static <T> List<T> getListFromCache( String cacheName, String key, CacheCreation<T> cacheCreation){
        List<T> all = new ArrayList<T>();
            
        Ehcache cache = getCache(cacheName);
        Element element = null;
        if(cache!=null){
            element = cache.get(key);
        }
            
        if(element==null){
            System.out.println(" : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the element '"+key+"' has not been found in the cache ---> get the original data.");

            all = cacheCreation.getAll();
            cache.put(new Element(key, all));
            System.out.println(" : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the original data for the element '"+key+"' has been added in the cache.");


        }else{
            System.out.println(" : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the element '"+key+"' has been found in the cache.");

          
            all = (List<T>) element.getObjectValue();
        }
        return all;

    }
    public List<String> getAllData1(){
        return getListFromCache( CACHE_NAME, "data1", new CacheCreation<String>(){
            @Override
            public List<String> getAll(){
                System.out.println(" : UseCaseClass.getAllData1() : the target original method is called to get the values.");
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("data1-value1");
                list.add("data1-value2");
                list.add("data1-value3");
                list.add("data1-value4");
                return list;
            }
        });
    }

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EhcacheWrapper wrappertest=new EhcacheWrapper();
        wrappertest.getAllData1();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           
           
        }
        wrappertest.getAllData1();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          
        }
        wrappertest.getAllData1();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           
        }
        

     

    }
}
```

When i run program i am getting following output

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
May 15, 2013 1:52:36 PM net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager resolveAndLockIfNeeded
WARNING: diskStorePath 'C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp' is already used by an existing CacheManager either in the same VM or in a different process.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp\ehcache_auto_created3199473242323720768diskstore.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
 : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the element 'data1' has not been found in the cache ---> get the original data.
 : UseCaseClass.getAllData1() : the target original method is called to get the values.
 : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the original data for the element 'data1' has been added in the cache.
 : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the element 'data1' has been found in the cache.
 : CacheUtil.getListFromCache() : the element 'data1' has been found in the cache.
```

**Though i am getting expected output but there is error in beginning saying :**

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
May 15, 2013 1:52:36 PM net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager resolveAndLockIfNeeded
WARNING: diskStorePath 'C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp' is already used by an existing CacheManager either in the same VM or in a different process.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp\ehcache_auto_created3199473242323720768diskstore.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
```

I look in
[slf4j-api version does not match that of the binding](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch)
for error but i could not get error for this

I saw similar error here [EhCache: Simple Program not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017961/ehcache-simple-program-not-working)
But it is taking about distributed cache.
For code i took reference from
[Java/Ehcache: A simple example of use of Ehcache 2.6.2](http://www.javablog.fr/javaehcache-a-simple-example-of-use-of-ehcache-2-6-2.html)

Any help please why i am getting error in beginning?

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says

```
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
```

The following line using `SingletonEhCacheProvider` may fix your issue

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</property>
```

[image: SingletonEhCacheProvider]